# Normal-format diff files giving "only garbage" error...don't want unified/context

Tags: linux, diff, patch

I'm trying to use the normal format to create a patch and then apply it.  Despite `-n` on both `diff` and `patch`, and an explicit file output `-o` on `patch`, I get the error:

```
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

How can I solve this?  I can't use unified or context patches in this case, so that's not a solution.

Is it a bug or something?  Editor format seems to work, for some reason:

```
$ echo a > a.txt
$ echo b > b.txt
$ diff -n a.txt b.txt > ab.diff
$ patch -n -o a.txt a.txt ab.diff
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
$ diff -e a.txt b.txt > ab.diff
$ patch -e -o a.txt a.txt ab.diff
$ diff a.txt b.txt
$
```

This is on Linux Mint 16, with:

```
$ diff --version
diff (GNU diffutils) 3.2
$ patch --version
GNU patch 2.7.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) of `diff`, you are not using the normal diff format with `-n` but the [RCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System) one:

> ```
> -n --rcs
>    Output an RCS format diff.
> ```

In order to use the normal format you can use the `--normal` option.
In the [`patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) command instead `-n` specifies the normal mode. So it's not a bug, more an unhappy naming convention.

### Example

```
$ echo a > a.txt
$ echo b > b.txt
$ diff --normal a.txt b.txt > ab.diff
$ patch --normal a.txt ab.diff
$ diff a.txt b.txt
$
```

*(You can avoid the `--normal` flags since they are the default format for both the commands)*

Comment: I even read that, and it failed to click in my mind, unhappily as you say.  Thanks for your help, it now works perfectly, of course.  :)